# To delete duplicate rows in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I've used this code to select the duplicate rows, it went right,

```
SELECT name, COUNT(name) 
  FROM emp
 GROUP BY name 
HAVING COUNT>1;
```

But it doesn't help me in deleting the same selected rows....

```
DELETE emp 
 WHERE name IN ( SELECT name, COUNT(name) 
                   FROM emp 
                  GROUP BY name 
                 HAVING COUNT >1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the second column from the inner `SELECT`, something like this:

```
DELETE
  FROM emp
  WHERE name IN( SELECT name FROM emp GROPU BY name HAVING COUNT(name) > 1)
```

Comment: Got it...Usagi...tq

Comment: I've added a rownum to retain 1 record.

DELETE
  FROM emp a
  WHERE a.name IN( SELECT b.name FROM emp b where a.name = b.name  GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(b.name) > 1)
  and rownum IN( SELECT count(c.name) - 1 FROM emp c where a.name = c.name GROUP BY c.name );